# .Net Regex to Extract 'Name & Address:' data but not title, where data may be on 1 - 3 lines

Tags: regex-group

I tried numerous variations of this regex, but results include unwanted spaces or 'Company'. The regex must be pure without any programming, substitutions or additional processing. Each name and address data set has data before and after. Company data always follows name & address data.

```
(?im)(?<=^Name\s?&\s?Address:\s+)([A-z0-9,./ -]+)(?:\r\s*(Company)?)([A-z0-9,./ -]+)
```

Sample data combinations:

xyz
Name & Address:    Bob Smith  341 Water St. Greenville, NY 10294
Company Name:  Smith BlackSmiths & Sons
xyz
Name & Address:   Charles Allan Robertson
    1234 The Strip  Las Vegas, NV  89776
Company Name:   Slots Etc.
xyz
Name & Address:   Frederick Mehltrettor
 Apt. 876-1  Kingston Ave
      Momento, California 93851
Company Name:   Fred's Momenentos
xyz
Name & Address:  
  Penelope Parkenfarker
  99 Highland Ave.
  Tulsa OK  65446
Company Name:    Bank of OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a simple regex like this?

```
Var nameAndAddresses = Regex.Matches(source, "Name & Address:([\\s\\S]+?)Company Name");
```

Comment: Thanks but this context is in a program language. I  must have a pure regex like the regex in my post. I tried the regex itself and it returns the Name & Address as well as Company Name, neither of which I need.

Comment: And this one?
`Regex.Matches(source, "(?im)(?<=^Name & Address:\\s*)([\\s\\S]+?)(?=\\r\\n^Company Name)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)`

Comment: I used t he essence of your expression, added look behind and look ahead expressions and found that is works except for a few spaces. Kudos for simplifying my complex expression. Well done!    This is the pure expression that works.      (?<=Name & Address:\s*)([\s\S]+?)(?=Company Name)

Comment: Definitely accepted answer. Where do I indicate that? This was my first question.

Comment: Basically, \s\S+? is a trick.
\s\S are apposites, so it is everyting (a single charater).
\s\S+ is the whole source because the cursor always forward.
\s\S+? go forward, until the following is found